# How can I fix this so it adds an info.txt into each newly created folder, not in the parent folder?

Tags: python, file-handling

I have this which makes directories and then creates txt files. But it creates the txt files in the main parent dir. I want one info.txt in each newly created folder. How can I fix?

```
import os

parent_dir = r"C:\America"
text_file = r"C:\dir.txt"
info_file = "info.txt"

with open(text_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        path = os.path.join(parent_dir, line)
        new_dir = os.mkdir(path)
        with open(path + info_file, 'w') as filehandle:
            filehandle.writelines('test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `os.path.join()` when creating that final filename too, instead of `path + info_file`.

If `path` doesn't have a slash at the end, with e.g. `path = "test"` you'd get `"testinfo.txt"`, which is a relative pathname for a file in the working directory – `os.path.join()` adds the delimiter if it isn't there. (To be clear, in your case, if `line` is `"test"`, `path` would end up being `"C:\America\test"`, and adding `info.txt` to that, you'd get `"C:\America\testinfo.txt"`.)

You may also wish to use `os.makedirs()` to create the full folder path, if necessary; `os.mkdir()` would raise an exception if an intermediate folder isn't there, or if the target folder already is there.

```py
with open(text_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        path = os.path.join(parent_dir, line)
        os.mkdir(path)
        info = os.path.join(path, info_file)
        with open(info, 'w') as filehandle:
            filehandle.writelines('test')
```

Comment: Funny how they took my comment away and gave you sole credit for my half of the contribution. LOL Nice try sneaking it past Sundream Dubey